# Flutter floor You are trying to change an object which is not an entity

Tags: flutter, flutter-floor

I have 2 Entities in my Flutter project. User and Team. I add User as an Entity and generate the autogenerated code successfully.

After this, i add the Team Entity, with the same way and got the error:

> You are trying to change an object which is not an entity

for my insert method.

My User Entity:

```
@entity
class User {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int? id;

  String firstName = "";

  User({
    this.id,
    required this.firstName,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'firstName': firstName,
    };
  }
}
```

My user_dao:

```
@dao
abstract class UserDao {
  @Query('SELECT * FROM user')
  Future<List<User>> findAllUsers();

  @Query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id')
  Future<User?> findUserById(int id);

  @insert
  Future<void> insertUser(User user);

  @update
  Future<void> updateUser(User user);

  @delete
  Future<void> deleteUser(User user);
}
```

And my database:

```
@Database(version: 1, entities: [User])
abstract class AppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
  UserDao get userDao;
}
```

This is working pretty fine.

Now i add my Team Entity:

```
@entity
class Team {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int? id;

  String name = "";

  Team({
    this.id,
    required this.name
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
  }
}
```

And my team_dao as well:

```
@dao
abstract class TeamDao {
  @Query('SELECT * FROM team')
  Future<List<Team>> findAllTeams();

  @Query('SELECT * FROM team WHERE id = :id')
  Future<Team?> findTeamById(int id);

  @insert
  Future<void> insertTeam(Team team);

  @update
  Future<void> updateTeam(Team team);

  @delete
  Future<void> deleteTeam(Team team);
}
```

After all, i add the new dao to the database:

```
@Database(version: 1, entities: [User])
@Database(version: 2, entities: [Team])
abstract class AppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
  UserDao get userDao;
  TeamDao get teamDao;
}
```

But now, i got the error message for my team_doa

> You are trying to change an object which is not an entity

```
Future<void> insertTeam(Team team);
```

But i don't understand why? Or did i some mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i found the problem.

I had to change:

```
@Database(version: 1, entities: [User])
@Database(version: 2, entities: [Team])
```

to

```
@Database(version: 2, entities: [User, Team])
```

and the database.g.dart will be generated